# Copying text in the yellow box appearing near a figure in Adobe Acrobat by moving the mouse

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro; in some slides, when I move the mouse over a figure, a yellow box with text appears. I'd like to know if there is a way to copy the text inside that box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If Acrobat doesn't give you any means of getting this text by
right-click on the object, then here is a non-perfect method that
I use in cases where I need to get the text out of a non-textual
context:

- Take a screenshot of the screen, or better of just the text area
- Use an OCR to extract the text from the image.

For example, I use the two tools :

- [Greenshot](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot) -
  an open-source screenshot tool
- [Capture2Text](https://capture2text.sourceforge.net/) -
  an open-source OCR.

Here is what I got for your yellow text with Capture2Text:

> http:// irawiki.disco.unimib.itf‌irawiki/ images/thumb/f/f2/ Funz
> ionamento_sensore_infrarossi.png/400px-Funzionamento_sen
> sore_infrarossi.png

Note that there are a few errors, so this is not perfect.
Some extra blanks were added, and the string "itf‌irawiki"
should have been "it/irawiki".

However, even with errors, these tools are great for extracting text
that is displayed in images or on the screen.

Comment: Hello @harrymc thank you for the solutions; I hope to find also a workaround to copy the text directly inside Adobe.